# Get static methods of a class nested in an object using Java reflection

Tags: scala, reflection

I want to get the list of methods in a nested companion object using Java reflection. This is `A.B` in the example below.

```
object A {
  object B {
    def foo: Int = 4
  }

  class B {}

  def bar: Int = 5
}

class A {}

// This works, `bar` is printed.
println(classOf[A].getMethods.map(_.getName).mkString("\n"))

// This doesn't work, `foo` is not printed.
println(classOf[A.B].getMethods.map(_.getName).mkString("\n"))
```

Seems like getting the list of methods on the outer companion object `A` works, but not on the nested one.

Is there any way to write a method that would take a `Class[_]` and get all the methods defined on the companion object whether it's nested or not?

Comment: Are you sure you pasted the correct code? I can't seem to reproduce the first print as you stated.

Comment: And classOf[A] can't possibly have a method `bar`, otherwise `new A` would also have a method bar.

Comment: Check this repl session https://gist.github.com/pedrofurla/d48d1f1fc759e2849400cb91fc69695b out

Comment: @pedrofurla This can be easily reproduced in a Scala script, but not in the REPL.

Comment: Not, it can not: http://scastie.org/23270

Comment: Don't see how I can get more empirical than this.

Comment: In your code, the object A is nested inside the Main object. Here is what you get when you make it a top-level object: http://scastie.org/23296

Comment: omg... I will check it out futher

Answer (score 1):

`classOf[A]` and `classOf[A.B]` are not the classes of the companion objects, so they don't have these methods. `A.type` and `B.type` sortof are but they aren't class types in Scala. As pedrofurla points out, you can do this to reach them as java Class objects:

```
scala> A.getClass.getDeclaredMethods
res17: Array[java.lang.reflect.Method] = Array(public int A$.bar())

scala> A.B.getClass.getDeclaredMethods
res18: Array[java.lang.reflect.Method] = Array(public int A$B$.foo())
```

Comment: Notice that the `A` and `A.B` as the objects, not the classes.

Comment: There's an inconsistency with how scalac produces the classes for the companion objects. classOf[A] actually would have bar() defined on it as a *static* method (see http://scastie.org/23296). From some reason foo() would not be listed as static in A.B.getClass.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following code, which makes an assumption that the companion's class name can be determined by appending `$` to the class name.

This allows calling a method on the companion given the class of a corresponding type, regardless of whether the companion is nested or not:

```
def getCompanion(clazz: Class[_]) = {
  Class.forName(clazz.getName + "$").getField("MODULE$").get(())
}

def companionMethod(clazz: Class[_], methodName: String) = {
  getCompanion(clazz).getClass.getMethod(methodName).invoke(companion)
}

// Print all companion methods:
println(getCompanion(classOf[A.B]).getMethods.map(_.getName).mkString("\n"))

println(companionMethod(classOf[A], "bar") == 5)
println(companionMethod(classOf[A.B], "foo") == 4)
```